# Is it possible to use fill box or bar plot with hatched pattern in R's ggplot2 package?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using ggplot2 to draw graphs on my results and I'm aware that hatched plot are old fashioned. But I'm constantly being asked to draw graphs with this filling pattern on my reports.

Is it possible?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Four year old information would say... no (if it makes you feel better, for a good reason). If you want hatching, there's plenty of support for that in base graphics.

Comment: I would suggest other attributes such as color, direct labels on bars, faceting etc.  See [this](http://www.perceptualedge.com/blog/?p=1756) Stephen Few article on hatching/pattern fill.  [Here](http://www.startvg.com/img/webimages/illusionmove.jpg) is an extreme bersion of pattern fills gone bad.  Thought I doubt you'd choose a fill this heinous it still distracts from the data as it requires more mental focus.